# What is the meaning of predicate "simple/1" in Prolog (SWI-Prolog)

Tags: prolog, predicates, iso-prolog

I run into problem while reading a book.
I see a program use predicate "simple" ( I guess `simple/1` ). I don't know what is the meaning of this predicate, I can't find it with  `?-help(simple)` in the console. 
But when I tried with some queries in console, it worked something like:

```
5 ?- simple(p(x)).
false.

6 ?- simple(mia).
true.

7 ?- simple(Mia).
true.

8 ?- simple(f(Mia)).
false.
```

I guess it is some sort of predicate to determine if the argument was Terms(or Variables) or Complex Terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [swi-prolog manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=quintus%3asimple/1) has the following definition:

> simple(@Term) is semidet
>       Term is atomic or a variable.

the definition is in the quintus prolog compatibility library; in the [quintus prolog documentation](https://www.sics.se/isl/quintus/html/quintus/mpg-ref-simple.html#mpg-ref-simple) the definition is:

> simple(+Term)
>
> Term is currently instantiated to either an atom, a number, a database
>   or a variable.

in any case, simple/1 is true if the argument is a simple term (not sure what the quintus manuals means by database; possibly a handler for an ODBC connection i guess)

Answer (score 0):

translated to ISO predicates:

```
simple(T) :- var(T) ; atomic(T).
```

**var/1** it's the most basic metaprogramming device, because it's impossible to predicate (i.e. execute code, *binding* variables) about any clause without instancing the variables, that are many times the essential part we are interested to.

Comment: As a general remark - a definition like `simple/1` is not very helpful because it merges two levels of testing into one predicate.

Comment: @false: do you mean that the disjunction introduces an useless choice point? I don't know what 'levels of testing' are...

Comment: When you write predicates that explicitly depend on the instantiation of an argument, it is a good idea to separate the testing for instantiations `var(X)`, `nonvar(X)` from the other testing. In particular, it is a good idea to treat both cases explicitly. Otherwise, it gets pretty hard to reason about a predicate. `simple/1` mixes both levels. And, btw. also `atom/1`, `integer/1` etc do this. But they are less problematic, if you do a `var`/`nonvar` test before.