# Is there a Prolog name for atom/1 or stream/1 etc (SWI-Prolog)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Just made a funny observation. SWI-Prolog allows other things than
atom as a functor in a compound. For example it allows me to do:

```
/* atom as functor */
?- Y =.. [foo, bar].
Y = foo(bar).

/* stream as functor */
?- current_input(X), Y =.. [X, bar].
X = <stream>(0000000069066420),
Y = <stream>(0000000069066420)(bar).
```

I wonder whether there is a name for what is allowed as a functor,
i.e atom or stream etc.. . The error message by SWI-Prolog doesn't
tell me what is the name, it says it expects an atom:

```
?- Y =.. [1, bar].
ERROR: Type error: `atom' expected, found `1' (an integer)
```

But as can be seen a stream etc.. , which is accepted, is not an atom:

```
?- current_input(X), atom(X).
false.
```

What is the umbrella type for what SWI-Prolog accepts as functor?
P.S. My guess why this is allowed: It is for example used for Dicts,
dicts are compounds with a special functor C'dict'.

**Edit 10.09.2021:**
I first thought its simple/1. But simple/1 is reserved
for atom or var, according to this answer:
[What is the meaning of predicate "simple/1" in Prolog (SWI-Prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9042879/502187)

Comment: The "special" name for the dict functor is a blob of type "reserved symbol". Another example for a reserved symbol is `[]` in SWI-Prolog which is not an atom. You can type `[]` in your source but I don't know another way to make the `C'dict'` thingy, you have to use `_{} =.. [X|_]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, **blobs** (**b**inary **l**arge **ob**ject**s**) are used to store arbitrary binary data, including atoms, images, and stream handles. Particularly, a blob represening a stream handle is a unique symbol which has no syntactical representation (although it is outputted  as `<stream>(hex-number)`).

The built-in predicate [`blob/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=blob/2) can be used to get the type of a blob:

```
?- X = foo, blob(X,Y).
X = foo,
Y = text.

?- current_input(X), blob(X,Y).
X = <stream>(0000000069057160),
Y = stream.
```

Thus, I think the type accepted as functor in SWI-Prolog is **blob**.

Answer (score -1):

In Dogelog Runtime we recently introduced a new type tester called `symbol/1`. One can imagine that it is bootstrapped from `blob/2` as follows:

```
symbol(X) :- blob(X, _).
```

[Dogelog Runtime](http://www.dogelog.ch/) does also accept symbols as functors, similar like SWI-Prolog. This is used to inline disjunction and if-then-else, and could have further optimization use cases. Functors are not only restricted to atoms, they can be atoms or references:

```
/* Dogelog Runtime, 0.9.6 */
?- current_input(X), atom(X).
fail.

?- current_input(X), Y =.. [X, bar].
X = [object Object], Y = [object Object](bar).
```

But I am currently thinking about extending `(=..)/2` even more. Namely to allow a compound as functor. What should a compound as functor do? Very simple:

```
/* Expected Result */
?- X =.. [foo(bar), baz].
X = foo(bar, baz)
```

So `(=..)/2` would add the arguments to the given compound. This further extension of `(=..)/2` doesn't need a new data type in the compound functor, but rather changes its behaviour.

It would have a couple of use cases:

- **Old Higher Order:**
  Bootstrapping apply/2 would be as easy as:

  ```
  apply(X,L) :- G =.. [X|L], G.
  ```
- **New Higher Order:**
  Bottstrapping call/n would be as easy as:

  ```
  call(X,Y) :- G =.. [X,Y], G.
  call(X,Y,Z) :- G =.. [X,Y,Z], G.
  call(X,Y,Z,T) :- G =.. [X,Y,Z,T], G.
  Etc..
  ```
- **DCG Expansion:**
  Expanding a non-terminal by an input and output list would be only a matter of calling (=..)/2. Here is an example:

  ```
  ?- G =.. [np(X),I,O].
  G = np(X,I,O).
  ```